# Instantiation not working for a threading reason

Tags: c#, json, multithreading, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I receive the following error

> "INTERNAL_CALL_Internal_InstantiateSingle can only be called from the main thread."
>       "Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene."
>       "Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function."

whenever I try to instantiate some `GameObject's` using this function:

```
public void DisplayCalls () {
    for (int i = 0; i < calls [0].Count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < impFields.Length; j++) {
            GameObject textClone = Instantiate (textBox, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.zero)) as GameObject;
            textClone.transform.SetParent (canvas.transform);
            Text text = textClone.GetComponent <Text> ();
            text.text = calls[impFields [j]][i];
            text.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
            textClone.transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (-262.5f + (175f * j), (182f + (30f * i)), 0f);
        }
    }
}
```

The function is called using this other function:

```
public void GetPanelInfo () {
    string file = "getpanelinfo.php";
    string hash = Md5Sum (mostRecentID.ToString () + SecretKey1 + SecretKey2);
    string parameters = "?mostrecentid=" + mostRecentID.ToString () + "&hash=" + hash;
    string fullURL = baseURL + file + parameters;
    Uri fullURI = new Uri (fullURL);
    WebClient client = new WebClient ();

    string jsonString = string.Empty;
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => {
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null) {
            jsonString = e.Result;
            JSONNode json = JSON.Parse (jsonString);
            for (int i = 0; i < json["calls"].Count; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < calls.Length; j++) {
                    calls[j].Add (json["calls"][i][names [j]]);
                }
                mostRecentID = json["calls"][i]["callID"].AsInt;
            }
        } else if (e.Cancelled && e.Error == null) {
            Debug.Log ("Cancelled");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Error: " + e.Error);
        }
        loading = false;
        LogCalls ();
        DisplayCalls ();

    };
    client.DownloadStringAsync (fullURI);
}
```

Which is called once using a button.

I cannot seem to find the problem, but as stated above, the error says that it is a threading problem and that I cannot call instantiate from another thread other than the main one. I do not know how to change the instantiation to another thread, but any help to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: What framework does `GameObject` belong to?

Comment: Is this using Unity?

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry, I forgot to include a Unity tag. Yes it is using Unity.

Comment: You are going to have to use some kind of delegate to bridge the threads.

Comment: @Reasurria May you elaborate?

Comment: @Cold999 I'll post an answer but I'm rusty on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TAKEN FROM MY [SAME QUESTION ON THE GAME DEVELOPMENT EXCHANGE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105491/instantiation-of-a-gameobject-not-working-for-a-threading-reason#105496).** 
**ANSWERED THERE BY [trojanfro](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/6423/trojanfoe).**

---

Looking at the [WebClient docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.WebClient/), the method is described as:

> Downloads a `string` from a resource, without blocking the calling thread.

and given the error message:

> `INTERNAL_CALL_Internal_InstantiateSingle` can only be called from the main thread

It's clear that you need to download the data and store it, and only call `DisplayCells`, in the main thread, once the download is complete.  This is not unique as in Cocoa, for example, you can only call UI-related API methods on the main thread.

It took me some hunting on Google to find any decent info on this (I am a beginner when it comes to Unity/C#), but I *think* this will do it:

Create a boolean that is shows there is data to display:

```
private bool _callsToDisplay = false;
```

Set that when the data has downloaded:

```
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) => {
    ...
    loading = false;
    LogCalls ();
    _callsToDisplay = true;
};
```

and then in the `Update()` method (which runs on the main thread), call `DisplayCalls()` if that boolean is set:

```
void Update()
{
    if (_callsToDisplay) {
        DisplayCalls();
        _callsToDisplay = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using UnityEvent to notify the main thread of events. The code will look something like the following:

```
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private UnityEvent m_MyEvent = new UnityEvent();

    void Start()
    {
        m_MyEvent.AddListener(DisplayCalls);
    }

    public void GetPanelInfo () {
        ...
        // instead of this : 
        // DisplayCalls (); 
        // do this:
        m_MyEvent.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I tried it and it still gives me the exact same error :/

Comment: Maybe it is the UnityEvent. The exact same solution is possible without using the unity engine. I think do a search on delegates and events. I think search for C# instead of unity. Something like "Send message to main thread C#" because there are plenty resources on this.